# Symfony2 Forms Adding New Entities on the fly

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I have 3 entities. `Customers`, `Products`, and `Purchases`.

New purchase forms should be able to be added by clicking an Add Another Purchase button. Every Purchase is a separate row in DB.

I have tried using a collection which fills/adds necessary number of forms for existing purchases for a customer but I'm not sure how to have a button to add additional purchase forms. Also, when adding a new customer, no purchase forms show.

I've been stuck on this for days!! PLEASE HELP

What is the best way to create a form like the following:

## Add/Edit New Customer

#### Customer Information

First Name
Last Name
Email

#### Purchases [Add Another Purchase Button]

1. Select Product (Dropdown retrieved from Products entity by User service) - Enter Quantity
2. Select Product (Dropdown retrieved from Products entity by User service) - Enter Quantity
3. Select Product (Dropdown retrieved from Products entity by User service) - Enter Quantity

[Add Another Purchase Button]

CustomersType Class

```
class CustomersType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('first_name')
            ->add('last_name')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('purchases', 'collection', array(
                'type'   => new PurchasesType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Customers',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'customers';
    }
}
```

PurchasesType Class

```
class PurchasesType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('products', 'entity', array(
                'class'         => 'My\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Products',
                'query_builder' => function ($repository) { return $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC'); }
            ))
            ->add('quantity')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\Purchases',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'purchases';
    }
}
```

Customers Class

```
class Customers
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $first_name;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $last_name;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $email;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="customers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="users", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $users;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Purchases", mappedBy="customers")
     */
    private $purchases;
}
```

Products entity

```
class Products
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $price = 0.0;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Purchases", mappedBy="products")
     */
    private $purchases;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="users", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $users;
}
```

Purchases Entity

```
class Purchases
{
    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $quantity;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Products", inversedBy="purchases")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="products", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customers", inversedBy="purchases")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fans", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customers;
}
```

Comment: At first glance you will need an customer.addPurchase method and you a cascade=all on the customer.purchases relation.  I know you want an actual answer but I'd suggest setting up a new application and then actually implement http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.  Might take awhile but at the end you will see all the little details required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go through the example in official documentation?

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

It has also an example about how to add new form collection by using javascript.